# Select and copy content in unique shape Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to select "Rectangle 132" in each slide, copy the content into the "outline menu" as a title for the slide using VBA.

Ultimately it would be nice to locate the "title" rubric above the actual slide, so it is not displayed on the slide.

```
Sub LoopThroughSlides()

'PURPOSE: Show how to loop through all slides in the active presentation

Dim sld As Slide
'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    'Do something...(ie add a transition to slides)

      Function getShapeByName(shapeName As String, Slide As Integer)
    Set getShapeByName = ActivePresentation.Slides(Slide).Shapes(shapeName)
End Function

Dim myshape As Shape
myshape = getShapeByName("Rectangle 132", 1)

  Next sld

End Function

End Sub
```

••••ˇˇˇˇ

I've found this but unsure how to apply it:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    If .Layout <> ppLayoutBlank Then

        With .Shapes

            If Not .HasTitle Then

                .AddTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Restored title"

            End If

        End With

    End If

End With
```

Comment: You've placed a Function inside a Sub. It should be outside. Please tell us what you're trying to accomplish, as there may be a better way to do it. Your second sub adds a Title, but you seem to want to avoid using the Title as the normal reference to a slide in an outline.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I would like the text in a shape (Rectangle 132) to be the title of each slide. So Rectangle 132 is the "real" title on each slide - but in the outline there is no title; I would like the title in the outline to be = Rectangle 132.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but titles don't work that way. The Title placeholder has a special status in the program that can't be transferred to other shapes. If you copy the text from Rectangle 132 and paste it to the Title placeholder, it will work as expected.

As an illustration of the special nature of the placeholder, I created a slide using the **Blank** layout, which has no Title. I opened Outline View, then typed text beside the slide thumbnail. This text is automatically considered the slide title and PowerPoint creates a Title placeholder on the blank slide, even though it didn't previously have one.

Comment: I would like to copy the text from Rectangle 132 and paste it into the title placeholder. It is exactly the function you're talking about in your 2nd paragraph I would like to utilize. 

I already have the text in each slide, represented by Rectangle 132.

Answer (score 0):

When you change your question, please consider starting a new thread, rather than tacking it on to the previous one. Give this VBA a try:

```
Sub SetTitle()
    Dim sld As Slide, oShape As Shape, TitleText As String, TitlePHName As String

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In sld.Shapes
            If oShape.Name = "Rectangle 132" Then
                If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                    If oShape.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                        TitleText = oShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If Left(oShape.Name, 5) = "Title" Then
                TitlePHName = oShape.Name
            End If
        Next oShape
        If sld.Layout <> ppLayoutBlank Then
            If sld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
                sld.Shapes(TitlePHName).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = TitleText
            Else
                sld.Shapes.AddTitle.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = TitleText
            End If
        End If
        TitlePHName = ""
        TitleText = ""
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the approach, not familiar with best practices at this site.

The script returns an error: Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request. This slide does not permit a title.
It bugs in this line:
 sld.Shapes.AddTitle.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = TitleText

Comment: The VBA I posted works on a standard Microsoft template. It sounds like you have more than just the blank layout that doesn't have a title placeholder. You'll have to handle that by revising the layout or adding another If Then statement to check the custom layout name.